# Как убрать тряску камеры из-за анимации?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Написал скрипт на переключение камер от 3-его лица на ***1**-ое лицо. **1** камеру пришлось поцепить прямо на голову из-за анимации персонажа чтобы текстуры не проходили через неё. После цепки камера начинает двигаться из-за анимации персонажа, так вот, каким образом можно убрать тряску камеры из-за анимации?

***1** - камера от первого лица.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решается очень просто, что даже скрипт выкладывать не буду, он очень примитивный. Решение: Камера - отдельный объект. С помощью скрипта меняю позицию камеры на позицию головы **(кости)**. Ну и сопоставляем значения **Position**

Comment: Это не ответ, в ответе был бы код скрипта. А так - это это у вас комментарий. Критерий проверки прост: следующему кто задаст вопрос поможет ваш комментарий? Нет - значит это не ответ. Намёки, куда двигаться для решения ответа принято оставлять комментариями под вопросом.

Answer (score 1):

В голову приходит три очевидных варианта:

1. Изменять position и rotation камеры с помощью чудесной функции интерполяции Mathf.Lerp. Она будет плавно приводить один вектор к другому, что значительно сгладит тряску. Так же работает с кватернионами.
2. Прицепить камеру к объекту, управляемому так же, как персонаж, но без анимации.
3. Прицепить объект к части персонажа, которая неподвижна, а на него уже повесить камеру

Уверен, есть что то более простое, но я художник, я так вижу (:

Comment: Интересно, как ты найдешь неподвижную часть объекта, если он полностью анимирован. Где логика? (: 2-3 варианты полный нелогичный бред... Попробую почитать за 1-й...

Comment: @PiT, "анимированную" часть персонажа (т.е. всего) помещаешь в дочерний объект, т.е. у тебя будет какой-нибудь `Character` со всей логикой и дочерний `Animated` с мешем и анимациями, камеру делаешь дочерним для `Character`, таким образом она не будет трястись из-за анимаций

Comment: В том то и дело. Смотри, если камеру повесить просто на персонажа **(не на кости)** , то при беге или прыжке она будет проходить сквозь персонажа, а это не есть хорошо. Если же повесить камеру на кость, то она нормально срабатывает при беге и прыжке, но вот тряска из-за анимации сильно раздражает. Решилось все очень просто. Я повесил камеру на персонажа **(не на кости)** и с помощью скрипта соединил камеру с костью головы. После этого выровнял камеру по **Position** **XYZ**.

Answer (score 0):

У unity есть бесплатный плагин [`Cinemachine`](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/cinemachine-79898), который как раз и предназначен для использования камеры для слежения за объектом, смены планов и всех тех фишек которые применяются в кино. Плагин немножко сложноват для понимания, но если вы с ним разберетесь, то он поможет вам делать очень приличные пролеты камеры или делать умную камеру для наблюдения за объектами.
Вот неплохие видеоуроки https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/animation/using-cinemachine-getting-started

В вашем случае настраивается две камеры, одна от первого лица, вторая от третьего. И в нужный момент у них меняется их значимость. Специальный контроллер `CinemachineBrain` автоматически без вашего участия не только сделает плавное переключение между камерами по выставленному приоритету, но и позволит настроить в редакторе как этот переход должен выглядеть.

В плагин встроены допустимые отклонения при движении объекта, чтобы избежать дерганья при проигрывании анимации и это позволяет делать плавное слежение за объектом. Камера может как следовать за объектом по заданным правилам, так и наблюдать находясь на одном месте. Вообще плагин очень богат на возможности, как то наблюдение за группами объектов, иммитация дрожание камеры при съемках с рук, переключение на камеру с лучшим обзором, перемещение камеры по заданной траектории и т.п.